# Play Game service Leaderboard Error

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, leaderboard

I've been tried the leaderboard but get errors, my app is called "Flindev I Love You", already uploaded to playstore.

Below is the error:

Screenshot that show only 2 users:

[image]

Screenshot that when I try using other account, it only show itself account, not retrieve other account:

[image]

even when i change the im in 1st to all ,,it only show my account or me ,,

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are seeing those players from your social circle. If you look closely there is a `toggle` button below **"I'm in 1st"**. Change it to all and you will see all the players who ever played the game.

Comment: no bro ,, iam wrong about the second screend shoot ,,, iwill update the question

Comment: So you cant see anyone else like in 2nd screenshot? but you can see another person when you use different account.

Comment: Please upload screenshots with "all" option selected.

Comment: i have switch the toggle to all but still in social or i dont know how to tell you ,, just like that ,,but do you have example about your success to implement play game service ?

Comment: I have never faced this issue before

Comment: please make tutorial about how to fix or make sure that all is fixed